# Use same SSL certificate for Tomcat and Nginx

Tags: ssl, nginx, tomcat7, ssl-certificate

I have got a SSL certificate for domain "www.example.com" and I have installed this certificate in tomcat server which runs on port 443 which runs fine. Now my requirement is to run nodejs code in https.

So i want to configure through nginx. So nginx will listen for incoming request and use ProxyPass. I am trying this but we get key mismatch error

So main question is:- Is it possible to use same certificate generated for tomcat keystore in Nginx

Comment: I know nothing about tomcat, but wouldn't nginx be effectively be handling the SSL for you? If so, you could just ProxyPass onto the HTTP (not HTTPS) port of tomcat?

Comment: i am doing same, but it seemd like certificate is not working, so my que is:- Is it possible to use same certificate (which is used for tomcat) for nginx.